# how to get rss feed in android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, rss

hi i am a new developer. In my app i have placed a list of edit boxes. When the user enters some data and click a button, i want that data to be stored in database and the same data's must hit to an URL and those data's to be listed as an XML file.

pls help me with an example coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Coding Green Robots](http://www.codinggreenrobots.com/) just did an episode on [getting data from RSS](http://www.codinggreenrobots.com/episodes/2011/3/8/episode-2-feed-me.html).  Download the sample code in the "Downloads" section.

Comment: your links seem to be broken